# Django 2.1 + Ecommerce : How to create a select Function for selecting a Product Color/Size from the client side?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

i am working on an Online Shop, and i want the customers to be able to select the product size and the color from the product page like this:

[image]

so far that's what i have accomplished:

[image]

but i can't select the Color nor the Size yet

here's my HTML Code:

```
...
<tr>
  <td class="my-prod-title">Color</td>
  <td>
      <ul id='color'>
         {% for color in product.color.all %}
            <li class="square my-2" style='background-color:{{color}};'>
           </li>
         {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="my-prod-title">Size</td>
   <td>
     <ul id='size'>
      {% for size in product.size.all %}
        <li class="my-2">{{size}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
   </td>
 </tr>
 ...
```

**What do i need to make that functionality ?**

Comment: are you using some kind of eCommerce package for it

Comment: No, just Django alone. @c.grey

Comment: show the stock products models

Comment: @panchicore sure !

Comment: @panchicore done!

Comment: create a radio field with name "color" and "size" respectively and modify css to make radio buttons look like your reference image. The button data should be rendered using `product.color.all`

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaKornepati i can work with that.